# Photoshop + Winform How to create 3d button press?

Tags: winforms, 3d, photoshop, photo

I am building a game, and I need an interface similar to the following.
(3D buttons, label, icon....)  If anyone is kind, please give me a video tutorial. I do not want to infringe copyright, so I will create beautiful products but not duplicate.
So I need to learn what kind of instructions to do, please send me a comment. Thank you everyone! 
I know that it is not related to code but I have asked in many places where there is no answer :( 
[image]

Comment: Easiest and quickest way would be to use ms-powerpoint. :) I know it ain't as good as photoshop but for quick edits it is my favorite. They have improved image editing a lot.

Comment: Use WPF with xaml instead of Winforms.

Comment: i dont know xaml :'(